# How to describe all integer solutions to $x^2+y^2=3z^2+1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

The question is in the title. Here is a short motivation. The general quadratic Diophantine equation is
$$
x^TAx+bx+c=0,
$$
where $x$ is a vector of $n$ variables, $A$ is $n \times n$ matrix with integer entries, $b$ vector, $c$ integer. We can try simplify it by linear substitution $x=Hy$, where $y$ are new variables and $H$ is $n\times n$ matrix with integer entries and determinant $\pm 1$. The equation becomes
$$
y^T(H^TAH)y + bHy + c = 0.
$$
The first entry in matrix $H^TAH$ is $h^TAh$, where $h$ is the first column of $H$. If there is a non-zero vector $h$ such that $h^TAh=0$, then in the new equation the $y_1^2$ term vanishes, and equation becomes linear in $y_1$. In many cases, this can be used to solve the equation.

The equation $x_1^2+x_2^2=3x_3^2+1$ is the simplest quadratic equation for which this method does not work. Here $h^TAh=0$ reduces to $h_1^2+h_2^2-3h_3^2=0$, which does not have non-trivial integer solutions. Hence, no linear substitution makes the equation linear in any of the variables. How to solve such equations?

There is a general method outlined by by Grunewald and Segal that should work for all quadratic equations: the idea is that (i) the integral orthogonal group of A is finitely generated, and there is an algorithm for listing the generators, and (ii) there is a finite set of solutions to the equation such that all other solutions can be constructed from this finite set by actions of this integral orthogonal group. However, how to implement this idea for this specific equation? Also, maybe there is an easier method?

I remark that I am looking for more or less explicit description of all integer solutions. The answer "Try $z=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\dots$ and for each $z$ list all representations of $3z^2+1$ as the sum of squares" does not count.

Comment: The general description and clarification of the solvability of such equations still comes down to clarifying the solvability of some equivalent Pell equation.
For some special cases, different combinations of formulas may arise. Their diversity can be very large.
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263153/indefinite-quadratic-form-universal-over-negative-integers   If you don't like the Pell equation very much. That is, the formula in that topic is the only option to approach the solution with a different approach.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, I now was able to solve the equation myself.

If $(x,y,z)$ is any solution, then $(y,x,z)$, $(x,-y,z)$, $(x,y,-z)$,  and $(x,3z-2y,2z-y)$ are also solutions. To check the last one, observe that
$$
x^2 + (3z-2y)^2 - 3(2z-y)^2 = x^2 + y^2 - 3z^2 = 1.
$$
All these transformations are invertible: if we apply any of them twice, we go back to the solution we have started with. To check this for the last one, observe that
$$
3(2z-y)-2(3z-2y) = y, \quad 2(2z-y)-(3z-2y)=z.
$$
Let us prove that all integer solutions to our equation can be produced from $(x,y,z)=(1,0,0)$ by a sequence of this transformations. This gives a complete description of the solution set.

Let us say that two solutions are in the same orbit if they can be obtained from each other by a sequence of these transformations. We will prove that all solutions are in the same orbit as $(1,0,0)$. In any orbit, choose a solution $(x,y,z)$ with $|z|$ minimal. By swapping $x$ and $y$ and changing signs of $y$ and $z$ if needed, we may assume that $0\leq |x|\leq y$ and $0\leq z$. Because this solution has minimal $|z|$ in the orbit, we must have $|2z-y|\geq z$. If $2z-y\geq 0$, this implies that $2z-y \geq z$, or $z \geq y$. But then $2z^2\geq 2y^2 \geq x^2+y^2 = 3z^2+1$, which is a contradiction. If $2z-y<0$, then $|2z-y|\geq z$ reduces to $y-2z\geq z$, or $y\geq 3z$. But then $9z^2 \leq y^2 \leq x^2+y^2 = 3z^2+1$, which is possible only if $z=0$. Hence, $(x,y,z)=(0,1,0)$, and, by applying the operation $(x,y,z)\to (y,x,z)$ for the last time, we arrive at $(x,y,z)=(1,0,0)$. Hence, all solutions are at the same orbit.

Comment: Because $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ can be transformed to each other, it does not matter to which one to arrive. I have added a few final lines to the proof.

Comment: This is one of the transformations of the Pell equations. The problem is that it's not that simple. For some equations, there may be more than one starting point for describing all solutions. And how is it possible to get $Y$ - an infinite number of possible solutions - $X ,Z$ for a given solution ?????

Comment: Yes, there may be more than one starting point, but there will always be finitely many starting points and finitely many operations. Because we can apply operations as many times as we want, this produces infinitely many solutions. Yes, I agree, finding all starting points and all operations may not be simple in general, but I am happy that it turned out to be simple at least for this simple equation.

Comment: I think in this case it is necessary to formulate a general task. Many very different problems are reduced to one equation. By the first decision. $(X,Y)$ Find the formula giving the following. In the equation. $aX^2+bXY+cY^2=f$ As for the usual Pell equation. Do you know this general formula?

Comment: I know the general method of Lagrange how to reduce any 2-variable quadratic to Pell equation and then solve it. I also read the formula for this specific equation from your blog.

Comment: Okay. I'll think about it then and if I succeed. Then I'll try to get this formula. If you don't mind, then I'll write her answer here.

Comment: You might want to see if you can chase down a copy of [The Sensual Quadratic Form](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0883850303) from John Conway; it talks about reductions of quadratic forms and gives various tree/hyperbolic structures that I suspect are germane to the transformation you give. There's also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples which may have some relevance, of course.