# On the equation $q(\mathbf{x}) = 1$ for $q$ a quadratic form

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms

Let $q(\mathbf{x}) = q(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ be a quadratic form with integer coefficients. For $n \geq 3$, is there a reasonable theory for the set of integer solutions to the equation

$$\displaystyle q(\mathbf{x}) = 1?$$

When $n = 2$ this is the well-known theory of Pell equations. Indeed, it is known that $q(\mathbf{x}) = 1$ has a solution in integers if and only if $q$ is $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$-equivalent to the principal form $x^2 - dy^2$ for some $d \geq 1$, and if $d$ is not a square, then there will be infinitely many solutions generates by a single fundamental solution.

Obviously, the same type of structure cannot exist for $n \geq 3$ since $q$ is in general geometrically irreducible, unlike the case when $n = 2$. Nevertheless, it would be nice to be able to describe the set of integer solutions in some reasonable way.

Comment: Do you have any sort of criteria for what would constitute a reasonable decription?  For example, would an emptiness vs. non-emptiness, or finite vs. infinite, classification be reasonable, or too weak?  (I don't know the answers even to these special cases, just am curious about what sort of answer is sought.)

Comment: @LSpice certainly Hasse's principle on rational solutions would be too weak (i.e., that there is a rational solution if and only if the equation has a local solution in every completion of $\mathbb{Q}$). I am mostly thinking about the case when there are infinitely many solutions, and what can be said about the set of solutions.

Comment: I am sure you are aware of this, but the solutions of $q(x_1,\dotsc,x_n)=1$ form finitely many orbits under the group of automorphs of $q$, and a solution exists if and only if $q$ is properly equivalent to a form $x_1^2+r(x_2,\dotsc,x_n)$.

Comment: See my answer to this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142938 about general quadratic equations.

Comment: For a nice example of equation of your type, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432091

Comment: in dimension 3  the  integer automorphism group of the form  can be parametrized by $SL_2 \mathbb Z$ This goes back to Fricke and Klein (1897)  and is displayed in Magnus, Noneuclidean Tesselations. Ummmm. The kids like parametrizations..., two I did in November..... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4802380/an-innocent-looking-quadratic-diophantine-equation  

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3221394/when-are-numbers-of-the-form-m29k2-pm-k-perfect-squares/4813669#4813669

Comment: and pages 301-309 in Cassels, Rational Quadratic Form s